# Trouble 'reversing' $\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=L\,\frac{d^2i(t)}{dt^2}+R\,\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}\,i(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

I'm having trouble with this differential equation. I would like to reverse it, and, in particular, express it in terms of $i(t)$ with on the other side some linear (integro-)differential operator on $v(t)$
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=L\,\frac{d^2i(t)}{dt^2}+R\,\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}\,i(t)\tag{1}$$

This is the common ODE of a RCL electric circuit with $v(t),\,i(t):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and $L,\,R,\,C\in\mathbb R_+$

Can anyone help me with the calculation i've done or with a totally new approach. Thanks a lot.

**Note**: I don't want to solve it, but my aim is to 'invert it', i.e. obtain some $i(t)=\mathcal Y[v(t)]$ with $Y[\,\cdot\,]$ linear operator, if possible.

---

What i've tried:

[Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) with $V(s)\equiv \mathcal L[v(t)]$ and $I(s)\equiv \mathcal L[i(t)]$, leads to
$$I(s)=\frac{s}{s^2\,L+s\,R+1/C}\,V(s)\tag{2}$$
Using [Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), for suitable $a,b \in\mathbb C$, i can rewrite it as
$$I(s)=\left(\frac{a}{s-s_1}+\frac{b}{s-s_2}\right)\,V(s)\tag{3}$$
where $s_1,\,s_2$ are the roots of the polynomial at denominator in eq. (2). Note that $a+b=1$.

Now, to come back to $t$ domain, i compute the [Inverse Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform), so that
\begin{align*}
i(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\lim_{T\to +\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}I(s)\,e^{st}\,ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\lim_{T\to +\infty}\left[
a\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{s-s_1}\,V(s)\,e^{st}\,ds
+b\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{s-s_2}\,V(s)\,e^{st}\,ds
\right]
\end{align*}
Now, i operate a change of variables, so that $\tilde s\equiv s-s_1$ and $\overline s\equiv s-s_2$, then
\begin{align*}
i(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\lim_{T\to +\infty}\left[
a\,e^{s_1 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\tilde s}\,V(\tilde s+s_1)\,e^{\tilde st}\,d\tilde s
+b\,e^{s_2 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\overline s}\,V(\overline s+s_2)\,e^{\overline st}\,d\overline s
\right]
\end{align*}
By [Laplace transform shifting property](https://mathalino.com/reviewer/advance-engineering-mathematics/first-shifting-property-laplace-transform), i have that $V(\tilde s+s_1)=\mathcal L[v(t)\,e^{-s_1 t}]$ and $V(\overline s+s_2)=\mathcal L[v(t)\,\,e^{-s_2 t}]$, so substituting this into last equation, and further recognizing Laplace transform of an integral, i can write
\begin{align*}
i(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\lim_{T\to +\infty}\left[
a\,e^{s_1 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\tilde s}\,\mathcal L[v(t)\,e^{-s_1 t}]\,e^{\tilde st}\,d\tilde s
+b\,e^{s_2 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\overline s}\,\mathcal L[v(t)\,e^{-s_2 t}]\,e^{\overline st}\,d\overline s
\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\left[
a\int_0^tv(\tau)\,d\tau
+b\int_0^tv(\tau)\,d\tau
\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,(a+b)\int_0^tv(\tau)\,d\tau\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\int_0^tv(\tau)\,d\tau
\end{align*}
which is clearly wrong, and i don't understand where mistake is.

---

**Edit**: Mistake is in last step, let me rewrite it
\begin{align*}
i(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,\lim_{T\to +\infty}\left[
a\,e^{s_1 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\tilde s}\,\mathcal L[v(t)\,e^{-s_1 t}]\,e^{\tilde st}\,d\tilde s
+b\,e^{s_2 t}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}\frac{1}{\overline s}\,\mathcal L[v(t)\,e^{-s_2 t}]\,e^{\overline st}\,d\overline s
\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,a\,e^{s_1 t}\int_0^tv(\tau)\,e^{-s_1 \tau}\,d\tau
+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\,b\,e^{s_2 t}\int_0^tv(\tau)\,e^{-s_2 \tau}\,d\tau
\end{align*}

And computing $a,b,s_1,s_2$ concludes the 'reversing' process, as indeed some linear integro-differential operator applied on $v(t)$ was found. Yes, at the end the quest turned out to be somewhat illusory, as this eventually coincides with ODE solution of (1).

**Still, i've some dubts on the change of variables, regarding the extremes of integration, how to treat them**

Comment: Oh yes, you are perfectly right, i cannot take that $e^{-s_2 t}$ out of $\mathcal L[\,\cdot\,]$.. Also this fact would make that step unmotivated..

Comment: Made correction, unfortunately result seems unvaried..

Comment: Once you write $i(t)=\text{known stuff}$ you have in some sense solved the equation. In any case, the integral operator $\mathcal{Y}$ you seek is an integral over the appropriate [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function)

Comment: @Sal Unfortunately i don't know enough about green function such to solve with it